# Saving parameter in my UsersController (devise) from a form in StripeAccountsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm wondering on the best route to go in to accomplish what I want to do..

first, my issue is that I want to save the form input from one controller to another controllers table.  but the way i have it isn't working.  how do i accomplish doing so?

Right now, I am attempting to simply save the stripe account token from the stripeaccount table to the users table under stripe_account.

stripe_account.acct_id >> user.stripe_account

Here's the stripe controller:

def create

```
    @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)



          acct = Stripe::Account.create({
          :country => "US",
          :type => "custom",
            legal_entity: {
              first_name: stripe_account_params[:first_name].capitalize,
              last_name: stripe_account_params[:last_name].capitalize,
              type: stripe_account_params[:account_type],
              dob: {
                day: stripe_account_params[:dob_day],
                month: stripe_account_params[:dob_month],
                year: stripe_account_params[:dob_year]
              },
              address: {
                line1: stripe_account_params[:address_line1],
                city: stripe_account_params[:address_city],
                state: stripe_account_params[:address_state],
                postal_code: stripe_account_params[:address_postal]
              },
              ssn_last_4: stripe_account_params[:ssn_last_4]
            },
            tos_acceptance: {
              date: Time.now.to_i,
              ip: request.remote_ip
            }

    })

    @stripe_account.acct_id = acct.id




    respond_to do |format|

      # @user = User.find(params[:id])

      if @stripe_account.save
        current_user = @user
        @user.stripe_account = acct.id
        format.html { redirect_to @stripe_account, notice: 'Stripe account was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stripe_account }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stripe_account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This alone doesn't worked, but i figured i would pass a hidden field in the @stripe_account form to throw the stripe account id into the users.stripe_account but that doesn't work either...
as you can see in the commented out piece of code, i tried finding by user ID as well but that brings up the error "can't find without user ID".

views:

```
     <%= form_for @stripe_account do | f | %>
...
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :address_postal, "Zip" %>
    <%= f.text_field :address_postal, class: "form-control input-lg", placeholder: "90210" %>
 </div>
 </div>
...
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
...
  <%= f.button "Create Account", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-custom", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Creating account..."} %>
```

The error i receive with the current code is:

```
undefined method `stripe_account=' for nil:NilClass
```

Other than solving this issue, is this the right way to go about it and most efficient.  The only other route i can think of is to create a joined table but not sure if it's a "better" or more efficient way and I'm hoping some more experienced coders can let me know which is best for this use case.

I have users signup, whether a buyer or seller, and then sellers can then add their banking information - so creating a user and stripeaccount isn't done together and i dont want it to be either (in case you're wondering why i don't just do it that way)

I would love to hear what you guys thoughts on this are. thanks for your time.

-- If you guys would like more information on my code, please feel free to let me know - but i think i got mostly everything that's important.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod the question has been answered

This is his response to a reformatted question:

I'm guessing you are only doing @stripe_account.save and not doing @user.save (why did you cut your method?).

You can add a @user.save or set the belongs_to assocaition with the autosave: true option.

I'd recommend you to change this:

```
@stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id
```

to this, though:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stripe_account = @user.build_stripe_account(stripe_account_params)
```

> Although, when i previously created this question, i wasn't as far as
>   i was when i ended up reformatting this similar question later on.

So in response to this question, they're response would be more like this:

I'd recommend you to change this:

```
@stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
```

to this, though:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@stripe_account = @user.build_stripe_account(stripe_account_params)
```

And then saving like this:

```
  if @stripe_account.save! && @user.save
```